# linkedin Oauth how to remember login

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, oauth, linkedin-api

I started out working with iOS development a few weeks ago, and recently I've been trying to integrate social networks into an app (Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn).  I managed to do the Facebook and Twitter sign in integration but I'm stuck on the LinkedIn.

Using this example for the LinkedIn integration https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client, I can sign in into LinkedIn, but once my app closes, I must re-sign in again.

What should I do in order for the app to remember the signed in User and how should i implement fetching feeds from LinkedIn  (Social, network etc) on the other views in my application using the access tokens from the signing in?

Comment: I haven't used that library, but the important part of oauth is to get an access token during auth and use it to sign subsequent requests.  That library is doing that somehow.  There should be a prominent getter and setter for the access token somewhere in there.  Once you find that, persist the token on the device after the first auth, on the next app start, read that value and set it again.

Comment: How should i persist the token on the device? Using NSUserDefaults somehow?

Comment: That's one way, or the file system, or keychain services (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1)

Comment: I seriously cannot understand how and where and on what to use the NSUserDefaults, file system or the keychain services. I really dont understand the code of the example I'm using, and there is no explanation for it.

Comment: Don't despair. It seems like a huge jumble at the start. Maybe consider starting with a simpler app?  Learn a very small app very thoroughly, then do a small step up. Don't worry about your speed. This will increase exponentially once you get going.

Comment: This is how you do it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952717/linkedin-login-saves-the-credentials-in-ios/22962168#22962168

Answer (score 0):

When user logged in to the app, you should request an access token via LinkedIn API. After that, you use NSUserDefaults to save this access token. So when User opens app, you check whether accesstoken exists or not. If accesstoken exists, user already logined in to the app.

```
- (void)getAccessToken:(NSString *)authorizationCode success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure 
{
   NSString *accessTokenUrl = @"/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=%@&redirect_uri=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@";
   NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:accessTokenUrl, authorizationCode, [self.application.redirectURL LIAEncode], self.application.clientId, self.application.clientSecret];

  [self POST:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   NSString *accessToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"access_token"];
   NSTimeInterval expiration = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"expires_in"] doubleValue];

   // store credentials
   NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   [userDefaults setObject:accessToken forKey:LINKEDIN_TOKEN_KEY];
   [userDefaults setDouble:expiration forKey:LINKEDIN_EXPIRATION_KEY];
   [userDefaults setDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] forKey:LINKEDIN_CREATION_KEY];
   [userDefaults synchronize];

   success(responseObject);
   }  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      failure(error);
   }];
}
```