# LinkedIn Login saves the credentials in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn to share the images. I need to login at first time after that it needs to save the LinkedIn credentials in the app. When i run the app next time again LinkedIn Login will display. How can i solve this problem.

[image]

I have saved the access token and passing that value, but still i am getting the error message like this "The partner did not properly implement the authentication protocol"

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? You need to store the data in cache somehow... use Core Data, use a Singleton class... Show us what you tried first.

Comment: The obvious place to save the credentials would be NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the accessToken:

```
self.accessToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody];
```

Save it in the user defaults so next time you can use it to avoid re-login:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:responseBody forKey:@"accessToken"];
```

Access back the accessToken:

```
NSString* accessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKeyPath:@"accessToken"];

OAMutableURLRequest *request =[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url consumer:self.consumer token:[[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:accessToken]];
```

Comment: Are you sure the Access Token from the response body is reusable. I believe OAuth uses a nonce?

Comment: For sure re-usable, although not nonce but it does have an expiry time. Moreover, you can also revoke it

Comment: I have saved the access token and passing that value, but still i am getting the error message like this "The partner did not properly implement the authentication protocol" as stated above